# see revision differences with TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, revisions

How do I see the differences between revisions 1 and 100 of an open source project with TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the History window, click on revision 1, then scroll up and Ctrl+click on revision 100, then right click and select "Show differences".

Comment: How do I make the History window appear?

Comment: I have just read...

Show the revision history of a file or folder. Also known as “Log”.

...thanks!